# I am always getting "Cannot read property 'GetEmployee' of undefined" while consuming service in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular tying to learn angular through youtube.The tutorial is for angular2.
I am trying to make a service and consuming in other class.But when i run my project i am always getting "Cannot read property 'GetEmployee' of undefined"
Below is my code

Below is the Service using which i am creating an object of employee and returning it.

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
  import { IEmployee } from './employee'

 @Injectable()
export class EmployeeService 
{
GetEmployee():  IEmployee[]
 {

     return [
         { code: 'emp01', name: 'Tom', gender: 'Male', annualSalary: 
     5500, dateOfBirth: '01/01/2010' },
         { code: 'emp01', name: 'Tom', gender: 'Male', annualSalary: 
    5500, dateOfBirth: '01/01/2010' },
         { code: 'emp01', name: 'Tom', gender: 'Male', annualSalary: 
      5500, dateOfBirth: '01/01/2010' },
         { code: 'emp01', name: 'Tom', gender: 'Male', annualSalary: 
       5500, dateOfBirth: '01/01/2010' },
         { code: 'emp01', name: 'Tom', gender: 'Male', annualSalary: 
   5500, dateOfBirth: '01/01/2010' }
     ];
  }
 }
```

IN the below code i am trying to consuming the service

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core'
 import { IEmployee } from './employee'
 import { EmployeeService } from './employee.service'

@Component
({
    selector: 'list-Employee',
    templateUrl: 'app/Employee/EmployeeList.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/Employee/EmployeeList.component.css'],
    providers: [EmployeeService]
})

export class EmployeeList {
selectedEmployeeCountRadioButton: string = 'All';
employees: IEmployee[];

private _emlployeeService: EmployeeService;

constructor(private _employeeService: EmployeeService) {
    this.employees = [
        { code: 'emp01', name: 'Tom', gender: 'Male', annualSalary: 5500, dateOfBirth: '01/01/2010' },
        { code: 'emp01', name: 'Tom', gender: 'Male', annualSalary: 5500, dateOfBirth: '01/01/2010' },
        { code: 'emp01', name: 'Tom', gender: 'Male', annualSalary: 5500, dateOfBirth: '01/01/2010' },
        { code: 'emp01', name: 'Tom', gender: 'Male', annualSalary: 5500, dateOfBirth: '01/01/2010' },
        { code: 'emp01', name: 'Tom', gender: 'Male', annualSalary: 5500, dateOfBirth: '01/01/2010' },
    ];
    alert(this._emlployeeService.GetEmployee());
    //  alert("asas")
    // this.employees=this._emlployeeService.GetEmployee();
}

getEmployee(): void {
    this.employees = [
        { code: 'emp01', name: 'Tom', gender: 'Male', annualSalary: 5500, dateOfBirth: '01/01/2010' },
        { code: 'emp01', name: 'Tom', gender: 'Male', annualSalary: 5500, dateOfBirth: '01/01/2010' },
        { code: 'emp01', name: 'Tom', gender: 'Male', annualSalary: 5500, dateOfBirth: '01/01/2010' },
        { code: 'emp01', name: 'Tom', gender: 'Male', annualSalary: 5500, dateOfBirth: '01/01/2010' },
        { code: 'emp01', name: 'Tom', gender: 'Male', annualSalary: 5500, dateOfBirth: '01/01/2010' },
        { code: 'emp08', name: 'Tomi', gender: 'FeMale', annualSalary: 5500, dateOfBirth: '01/01/2010' }
    ];
}
trackByEmpCode(empoyee: any): string {
    return empoyee.code;
}


onRadioButtonSelectionChanged(selectedPerson: string): void {
    this.selectedEmployeeCountRadioButton = selectedPerson;
    console.log("This " + this.selectedEmployeeCountRadioButton);

}
getTotalEmployeeCount(): number {
    return this.employees.length;
}
getTotalMaleEMployeeCount(): number {
    return this.employees.filter(e => e.gender == "Male").length;
}
getTotalFemaleEMployeeCount(): number {
    return this.employees.filter(e => e.gender == "FeMale").length;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Remove `private _emlployeeService: EmployeeService;` over the constructor.

By doing `constructor(private _employeeService: EmployeeService) {` you are already declaring the `_employeeService` property.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here.

First is a typo, `_emlployeeService`.

Second is this:

Within your `EmployeeList` component class, you are declaring a new `EmployeeService` using the following line:

```
private _emlployeeService: EmployeeService;
```

This is unnecessary because of Angular's Dependency Injection which is already giving you an instance of the `EmployeeService` class where you request it in your constructor here:

```
constructor(private _employeeService: EmployeeService)
```

The instance you are declaring yourself was declared, but not instantiated, thus it is `undefined`. Where you are calling the `GetEmployee` method, it is the undefined `EmployeeService` that is being used.

Comment: Thanks for the help.it's working after removing "private _emlployeeService: EmployeeService;"